# Multiple queries and poor perfomance in Entity Framework when using Distinct and Order By

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

The following LINQ query in EF (EFCore, v2.2.1)

```
    var x = context.Exchange 
            .Include(q => q.Input)
            .Where(q => q.InputId !=  1&& 
                q.Input.CreatedOnUtc > DateTime.Parse("2019-11-25") && 
                q.Input.UserId == 2 && 
                q.BotConversationId == 3)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(q => q.Input.CreatedOnUtc)
            .FirstOrDefault()
```

Ends up giving the profiled SQL results (simplified)

```
select * from (
    select distinct e.* 
    from Exchange e, ExchangeInput i 
    where e.InputId = i.InputId
    and e.InputId <> 1
    and i.UserId = 2
    and e.BotConversationId = 3
)
```

```
select * from ExchangeInput
```

Why does it need to do two separate queries?  The second query being horrendous when ExchangeInput might have millions of rows.
Surely, this would suffice:

```
select * from (
    select distinct e.*, i.CreatedOnUtc 
    from Exchange e, ExchangeInput i 
    where e.InputId = i.InputId
    and e.InputId <> 1
    and i.UserId = 2
    and e.BotConversationId = 3
) a
order by a.CreatedOnUtc
```

Also - putting the Distinct after the order by gives only 1 query as I would expect.

Fixing the problem is easy enough.  Adding a `.Select(...)` before the `.Distinct` or removing the `.Distinct()` will do it.  But the initial, poorly performing code, doesn't seem immediately problematic when reviewing it.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by suggesting that calling `Distinct()` before a `FirstOrDefault()` is unnecessary. The first row in a "non-distinct" query should always be the same as a "distinct" query when you have an OrderBy! As you mentioned in your last sentence, it seems that removing the `Distinct()` should only create one query.

Separate to your question, I would also suggest calculating `DateTime.Parse("2019-11-25")` outside of the query. That should allow you to pass it to the database server as a parameter and that might make your query even more efficient.

All in all, I would try:

```
var dateFilter = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-25");
var x = context.Exchange 
        .Include(q => q.Input)
        .Where(q => q.InputId != 1 && 
            q.Input.CreatedOnUtc > dateFilter && 
            q.Input.UserId == 2 && 
            q.BotConversationId == 3)
        .OrderBy(q => q.Input.CreatedOnUtc)
        .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: You are right, the distinct is not required.  My main issue is trying to understand why that kind of statement leads to such poor performance, when there seems to be an easy translation from the LINQ to SQL.